# How to add a button in grid row in Extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Currently, I am populating the data for my grid using XML file.

My XML file is something like this

```
<property>
    <category>Email</category>
    <name>To-address</name>
    <value>abc@xyz.com</value>
</property>   

<property>
    <category>Email</category>
    <name>From-address</name>
    <value>abc@xyz.com</value>
</property>
<property>
    <category>Email</category>
    <name>Email-body</name>
    <value>My Body</value>
</property>
<property>
    <category>Email</category>
    <name>Password</name>
    <value>1234</value>
</property>
```

And I am populating my grid like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'grid',
    columns: [{
            text: 'Name',
            width: 100,
            dataIndex: 'name'
        }, {
            text: 'Value',
            dataIndex: 'value',
            flex: 1,
            getEditor: function(record) {
                if (record.get('name') === 'password') {
                    return Ext.create('Ext.grid.CellEditor', {
                        field: Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
                            inputType: 'password'
                        })
                    })
                    else if (record.get('name') === 'Content') {
                        return Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Action', {
                            width: 50,
                            items: [{
                                iconCls: 'x-fa fa-cog',
                                tooltip: 'Edit',
                                handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                                    alert('Hello World');
                                }
                            }]
                        });
                    } else {
                        return Ext.create('Ext.grid.CellEditor', {
                            field: Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {})
                        })
                    },
                    renderer: function(value, meta, rec) {
                        if (record.get('name') === 'password') {
                            value = '***';
                        }
                        return value;
                    }

                }
            }
        ],
        selType: 'cellmodel',
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'cellediting',
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add a button to the Content row as value, which will be going to pop up a window to add email body to the user on click.

This is what I tried. It is able to add a button with handler working fine, but it is hiding other grid value column data

```
if (record.get('name') === 'Content') {
    var id = Ext.id();
    Ext.defer(function() {
        Ext.widget('button', {
            renderTo: id,
            text: 'Edit',
            width: 100,
            handler: function(record) {
                alert("Hello world");
            }
        });
    }, 50);
    return Ext.String.format('<div id="{0}"></div>', id);
}
```

As a preliminary step, I want to check an alert box for the action column I am adding the content. But it is not showing up in the row.

What I am missing here to add a button to the grid row?

Comment: You are going down a stony path with your `grid` approach to a `form` problem. If I were you, I would look into making the XML into a single record instead of four, and use a formpanel with fields. It will be at least a bit easier now and definitely far easier in the long run.

Comment: @Alexander Yes, I agree with you. As I have started with it already, wanted to know what I am missing here. Anyway thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

An editor is defined on a column, in your case, the column is of type `gridcolumn` (the default column type) and implicitly defined through

```
 text: 'Value',
 dataIndex: 'value',
 flex: 1,
```

The function `getEditor()` of a column should return an editor component with a field derived from `Ext.form.field.Base`.

However, you are sometimes returning a column component from the `getEditor`:

```
 getEditor: function(record){
     ...
     else if(record.get('name') === 'Content') {
          return Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Action', {
          ...
```

This cannot work because it is the wrong component type. Also, your column has a fixed type and you cannot get a single cell of the column to behave like a different column type, except by manually overriding the renderer. I don't see a quick fix for this. You could possibly return an editor with a textfield with a trigger button inside.

However, I would recommend that you use a `form` for your data, which is far more suitable. In that form, you can place buttons wherever you want.

Comment: Hi, yes I got that; the other approach what I implemented is that to overriding the renderer with a widget button. 
Which in fact displaying the button, to my surprise it is hiding all my grid Value column data. Don't know what is the mistake.

Comment: @AmitNekar Cannot say what you are doing wrong without seeing the code.

Comment: if(record.get('name') === 'Content'){

var id = Ext.id(); 

Ext.defer(function(){   

Ext.widget('button', {   

renderTo: id,

text: 'Edit', wdth: 100,    

handler:function(record)   
 {    alert("Hello world");   }
});  }, 50);

return Ext.String.format('<div id="{0}"></div>', id);


This is what I tried. It is able to add a button with handler working fine, but it is hiding other grid value column data